# how to create a pst file programmatically without installing outlook in java?

Tags: java, outlook, pst

I am using [java-libpst](https://github.com/rjohnsondev/java-libpst) to see what emails and email attachments are in there. Now I would like to create a new `pst file` from `pst file` but with `selected emails` and `email attachments`.

Comment: The commercial product Aspose.Email for Java might be of interest for you: http://www.aspose.com/java/email-component.aspx

Comment: You can also use Redemption and its RDOSession.LogonPstStore method (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm)  - it will work without Outlook installed if you install the standalone version of MAPI (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39045).